# How do i parse my output labels to my network?

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I am currently trying to train a cnn network which has 72 input and one output being a vector of length 24 stating the a class for each third input 72/24 = 3. There are 145 classes.

This is a similar example with a random generates dataset -  A preprocessing step is performed inside the model function which is necessary as the train input shape isn't the same, but for easiness of this example has shape been kept consistent.

```
#   Creating train input:
for i in range(974):
    nano_train_input.append(np.random.random((78,684,4)))
    nano_train_output.append(np.random.randint(145,size=(228)).tolist())

#   Creating test input:
for i in range(104):
    nano_test_input.append(np.random.random((78,684,4)))
    nano_test_output.append(np.random.randint(145,size=(228)).tolist())

def model(train_input, train_output, test_input, test_output, names=0):

    print "Type:"
    print type(train_input)
    print type(train_output)
    print type(test_input)
    print type(test_output)
    print
    print "len:"
    print len(train_input)
    print len(train_output)
    print len(test_input)
    print len(test_output)
    print
    print "Type[0]:"
    print type(train_input[0])
    print type(train_output[0])
    print type(test_input[0])
    print type(test_output[0])
    print
    print "shape of [0]:"
    print train_input[0].shape
    print len(train_output[0])
    print test_input[0].shape
    print len(test_output[0])
    raw_input("sad...")
    #data_train_input = np.empty((0,72,78,3))
    data_train_input = []
    #data_test_input = np.empty((0,72,78,3))
    data_test_input = []
    #   Paper uses dimension (40 x 45 =(15 * 3))
    #   Filter size 5
    #   Pooling size
    #   I use dimension (78  x 72 = (24 * 3)
    #   Filter size 9

    print "In model"
    i = 0
    print_once = True
    data_train_output = []
    for matrix in train_input:
        row,col,color = matrix.shape
        #out = np.empty((0,78,3))
        out = []
        remove = (col/3)%24
        remove_col = col%72
        #print "Col: " + str(col)
        #print "Removed output: " + str(remove)
        #print "Removed input: " + str(remove_col)
        #print "Before:"
        #print len(train_output[i])
        if remove > 0:
            train_output[i] = train_output[i][:-(remove)]
        #    print "After:"
        #    print len(train_output[i])
        #else:
            #print "After:"
            #print len(train_output[i])
        #raw_input("ASD")
        for splits in chunks(train_output[i],24):
            #print len(splits)
            #print np.array(splits).shape
            #data_train_output = np.append(data_train_output,[np.array(splits)],axis=0)
            if len(splits) == 24:
                data_train_output.append(np.array(splits))
        i=i+1
        for feature_map in xrange((col-remove_col)):
            #out = np.append(out,[matrix[:,feature_map,:-1]],axis=0)
            out.append(matrix[:,feature_map,:-1])
            #print out.shape
            if feature_map%72 == 0:
                #data_train_input = np.append(data_train_input,[out],axis=0)
                data_train_input.append(np.array(out))
                del out
                out = []
        #print "Length of train-input: " + str(len(data_train_input))
        #print "Length of train-output: " + str(len(data_train_output))
        #raw_input("ASdsad")
    print "done train-pit"

    print "After train_output/input"
    i = 0
    data_test_output = []
    for matrix in test_input:
        row,col,color = matrix.shape
        out = []
        remove = (col/3)%24
        remove_col = col%72
        #print "Col: " + str(col)
        #print "Removed output: " + str(remove)
        #print "Removed input: " + str(remove_col)
        #print "Before:"
        #print len(test_output[i])
        if remove > 0:
            test_output[i] = test_output[i][:-(remove)]
        #    print "After:"
        #    print len(test_output[i])
        #else:
        #   print "After - Not remove:"
        #   print len(test_output[i])
        #raw_input("ASD")
        for splits in chunks(test_output[i],24):
            if len(splits) == 24:
                data_test_output.append(np.array(splits))
        i=i+1
        for feature_map in xrange((col-remove_col)):            #out = np.append(out,[matrix[:,feature_map,:-1]],axis=0)
            out.append(matrix[:,feature_map,:-1])
            if feature_map%72 == 0:
                data_test_input.append(np.array(out))   #Maybe a reshape
                del out
                out = []
        #print "Length of train-input: " + str(len(data_test_input))
        #print "Length of train-output: " + str(len(data_test_output))
        #raw_input("ASdsad")
    print "After test_output/input"

    print "Length:"
    print len(data_train_input)
    print len(data_train_output)

    print len(data_test_input)
    print len(data_test_output)

    print "Type;"
    print type(data_train_input[0])
    print type(data_train_output[0])

    print "Size [0]"
    print data_train_input[0].shape
    print data_train_output[0].shape

    print "asarray - type: "
    print type(np.asarray(data_train_input))
    print type(np.asarray(data_train_output))

    print "asarray - shape: "
    print np.asarray(data_train_input).shape
    print np.asarray(data_train_output).shape

    print "asarray [0]- shape: "
    print np.asarray(data_train_input)[0].shape
    print np.asarray(data_train_output)[0].shape
    #raw_input("Ok?...")

    list_of_input = [Input(shape = (78,3)) for i in range(72)]
    list_of_conv_output = []
    list_of_max_out = []
    #list_of_flatten_out = []
    for i in range(72):
        list_of_conv_output.append(Conv1D(filters = 32 , kernel_size = 6 , padding = "same", activation = 'relu')(list_of_input[i]))
        list_of_max_out.append(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3)(list_of_conv_output[i]))
        #list_of_flatten_out.append(Flatten()(list_of_max_out[i]))

    merge = keras.layers.concatenate(list_of_max_out)

    reshape = Reshape((-1,))(merge)

    dense1 = Dense(units = 500, activation = 'relu',    name = "dense_1")(reshape)
    dense2 = Dense(units = 250, activation = 'relu',    name = "dense_2")(dense1)
    dense3 = Dense(units = 24 , activation = 'softmax', name = "dense_3")(dense2)

    model = Model(inputs = list_of_input , outputs = dense3)
    model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam" , metrics = [metrics.sparse_categorical_accuracy])

    reduce_lr=ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=3, verbose=1, mode='auto', epsilon=0.01, cooldown=0, min_lr=0.000000000000000000001)
    stop  = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=5, verbose=1, mode='auto')

    print "Train!"

    list_train_input = []
    list_test_input = []

    print model.summary()

    for i in range(len(data_train_input)):
        list_train_input.append(data_train_input[i])

    for i in range(len(data_test_input)):
        list_test_input.append(data_test_input[i])

    hist_current = model.fit(x = [np.array(list_train_input[i]) for i in range(72)],
                        y = np.asarray(data_train_output),
                        shuffle=False,
                        validation_data=([np.array(list_test_input[i]) for i in range(72)],np.asarray(data_test_output)),
                        validation_split=0.1,
                        epochs=150000,
                        verbose=1,
                        callbacks=[reduce_lr,stop])


del test_input_data
del test_name
del test_input_data_normalized
del test_name_normalized
del test_input_data_interweawed
del test_name_interweawed
#del test_input_data_interweawed_normalized
#del test_name_interweawed_normalized

del train_input_data
del train_name
del train_input_data_normalized
del train_name_normalized
del train_input_data_interweawed
del train_name_interweawed
#del train_input_data_interweawed_normalized
#del train_name_interweawed_normalized

model(nano_train_input,nano_train_output,nano_test_input, nano_test_output)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "keras_cnn_phoneme_classification.py", line 456, in <module>
    model(nano_train_input,nano_train_output,nano_test_input, nano_test_output)
  File "keras_cnn_phoneme_classification.py", line 435, in model
    callbacks=[reduce_lr,stop])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1405, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1299, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='model target')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 133, in _standardize_input_data
    str(array.shape))
ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected dense_3 to have shape (None, 1) but got array with shape (8766, 24)
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: May want to read [ask] and [mcve]...

Comment: I added a complete example

Answer (score 1):

A few remarks :

1. Why do you have `len(data_train_input) = 9436` and `len(data_train_output) = 9417` ? there are more inputs than outputs...
2. `dense3 = Dense(1 ,activation = 'softmax')(dense2)` : this doesn't make sense for 2 reasons, first the activation : a softmax will normalize the output so that they sum up to 1, if you have only one output, it will always become 1 because of that activation. Second reason, the number of outputs : I see that the shape of your targets is (24,)... Why do you ouput 1 value only out of your last dense ? If you try to classify between 24 classes change your last layer to :

   dense3 = Dense(24 ,activation = 'softmax')(dense2)
3. There will probably be more errors once you fixed that but I cannot debug it all at once just by looking at the code.

I hope this helps already a bit.

Comment: thanks :)
1. I fixed that.  
2. I tried changing it to 24, This gives the same error. 
3. Ahh.. You already knew..